# ArcGIS 10.2.2 Chart Graph data precision shown

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, graph, precision

I created a pie chart that had several pieces of data; pipe diameter to length of pipe per diameter. I summarized data from length of pipe and diameter from a database and input into a summary data table. I then tried to graph the table and the data shows up with 3 decimal points for the summarized lengths. I modified the editor options to indicate no decimal points and changed the table setting to show no decimal points.

Is there a simple way to change the precision of the data in the graph?

[image: table indicating 3 decimal points]

[image]

Comment: Been a long time since I created a chart in ArcMap, but I have a feeling you can just right-click on the chart to set display options

Comment: I tried this prior to posting and found there are no options I'm aware of to modify the precision of the data in the right-click properties and advanced properties menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no straight way to achieve this. Changing the decimal places from column properties will only change display properties of the numbers but whenever you are using them they will show up. To get rid of the decimal places try creating another column and round the number into it.

`new_column = round(!Summation of Length!, 2)`

Make sure you set the Parser to Python in the Field Calculator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I hoped that there was more options to control the appearance of the graph itself, the answer to create another column is acceptable. I also considered using excel and pasting the graph created in excel back into the MXD. Please provide any other options to control the output in the GIS graph that are available.

Comment: See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-features-to-show-quantities-drawing-pie-ch.htm) for more option for Pie charts . Access is even better than Excel at some point. Try [these options](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/65177) to dynamically link mxds with Access and see the changes in real time.